# Does B2C support Grant Flow with PKCE?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've been asked to integrate a new web app with our B2C implementation and the requirement is to support the Grant Flow with PKCE.

Does B2C/IEF support this?  Any pointers as to steps required?

I'm hopeful as I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) reference in the AD docs, which references `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` parameters in the request to the /authorize endpoint.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this developer announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/azure-ad-b2c-google-signin-issue/) and [this documentation issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11781), it is supported, although it isn't enabled for the implicit flow AFAIK.

Comment: Yes - it is supported - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce-in-azure-ad-b2c-9203fbc148fd

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to enable PKCE for the implicit flow as there's no code exchange in that flow.

Comment: Thanks @thomaux I believe I meant PKCE for SPAs when I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are trying to create a web based application that can only use Auth code with PKCE per the new OAuth guidelines. Please refer to the following post in regards to the new OAuth rules and Microsoft's Auth process : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/our-thoughts-on-implicit-grant-with-microsoft-identity/

Microsoft's suggestion is to utilize the Microsoft Libraries to do authentication, that is using either ADAL/MSAL.

As it's a B2C Application you will want to use MSAL. For more information on using MSAL please refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview

Comment: According to the call out at the top of this page, even though AADB2C supports Authorization Code with PKCE, the MSAL.js library does not support that flow with AADB2C. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code They recommend following this tutorial that uses Implicit Flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-single-page-app?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: Here is the github issue for MSAL.js v2 not working with AADB2C for Authorization Code flow with PKCE https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1795